# Creating a Deque Class methods

Tags: java

I need to write my own Deque class and must used a doublylinked list implementation to store data. the problem is writing the method pushfromLeft(Thing thing) which will insert into the left side of the deque. Below is what I have thus far but does not seem to work.

```
 public void pushLeft(Thing thing) {
         Node beg = new Node();  
         Node end = new Node();
         Node T = new Node();  

       if(isEmpty())
       { 
             beg = first;
             end = last;
             beg = end;
             T = beg.thing;
             N++;
       }
       else
       {
             beg = beg.next;
             end = end.next;
             T = beg.previous;
             N++;


       }
```

Comment: The best advice I *ever* got regarding building data structures and methods like this was to draw it out on paper before you write the code. Drawing it out will make it *very* obvious where you've gone wrong (though Matthew Flaschen points out the biggest problem with your code).

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 4):

Little you do in that method has any effect outside, except changing `N` and `item`.  Presumably you should be modifying `first`.  It would help if you provide the fields of your class, and what they mean, for context.  For instance, it's not clear what `item` is.

You should also either come up with different conventions for naming member and local variables, or consistently use `this.`, or both.

Answer (score 1):

Might I make a suggestion that may clear a lot of this up for you.  it's not what you asked for, but it may be what you need.

Use OO design, this means not operating on something but asking something to operate on itself.  What this means is that Node should be more intelligent--currently you are acting on node.

Since Node is doubly linked, it can be pretty smart!  It can have methods like:

```
newNode.insertBefore(currentNode)
newNode.insertAfter(currentNode) 
currentNode.remove()
```

Once you have those, the rest of your code should clean up a bit.  They should be trivial to implement given a doubly linked list.

```
void insertBefore(node existing) {
    // first set my stuff up
    previous = existing.previous;
    next = existing;
    // then point other stuff at me
    previous.next = this; 
    existing.previous = this;
}
```

I think--that's just off the top of my head.

The other question is how do you handle your "Endpoints".  Your first and last pointers have to be instances of Node for this to work, but if they are notice that the whole "If" factors out of your original code!  Sweet!

Just ALWAYS have a first and last object that start out pointing to each other (and never take on values).  When you do your first add, do first.insertAfter() or last.insertBefore() and you are done.

Another possibility, by the way, is to make the list circular--there is no reason that First and Last couldn't be the same "Special" unassigned node, you could still traverse it's Next (which will give you the first real item in the list) and Previous  (giving you the last item in your list).

When iterating the entire list, if .value == null, you know you've made it to the other end which makes node.next() and previous() fascinatingly easy to implement (You don't really even need to implement .next, but see below.

```
/** returns null if there are no more items in the list */
Node next() {
    return next;
}
```

Try it, it will simplify your code a LOT.  Most people really don't get how useful actual OO code is.

Also, make all your variables private, it's a good habit to get into.  In this case when you are having nodes operate on each other, they can still access each other's private members (not as dirty as it sounds) so you can still have the insertBefore as I wrote it AND you don't have to have getters and setters or public variables.  Best of both worlds.

Also notice how your original class that "Operated" on node all but disappears--in fact, it can go away completely. If you needed some specific methods like find(item) or insertSorted(item) there is no reason you couldn't add them to node itself.  This may be hard to see until after you implemented it though.

Funny how if you actually code well, most of the complaints people have about Java just don't come up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [LinkedList](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedList-source.html) source code as a reference?

Comment: That seemed to helped get a better understanding of the logic, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You definitly don't need to create more than one `Node` inside adding method. If you want to read from left AND from right later, each `Node` must remember previous and next element. Then when adding, you just need to re-locate these links, like this:

```
public void pushLeft(Thing thing) {
   Node newNode = new Node();  
   newNode.setValue(thing); //or just   newNode.value = thing;

   if(this.isEmpty())
   { 
         this.first = this.last = newNode;
         this.n=1;
   }
   else
   {
         this.first.previous = newNode;
         newNode.next = this.first;
         this.first = newNode;
         this.n++;
   }
}
```

It vould be wise to create a constuctor for Node class which shoul automaticaly set the value, then you can just wite:

```
Node newNode = new Node(thing);
```